# Why does my object instantiation work, but return null?

Tags: c#, unity

For some reason, the `LogError` runs:

```
Player clone = Instantiate(player, this.transform.position,
    Quaternion.identity) as Player;

if(!clone) { Debug.LogError("WTF"); }
else       { Debug.Log("WE GOT IT"); }
```

My object appears, but if I try to do anything with it afterwards  its value is `null`, and the `if(!clone)` triggers.

Why is this happening?

The player is a gameobject and is assigned (its my player prefab) and Player is what my prefab is called. I also have a `Player.cs` script. Is Unity confusing my prefab and script or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Instantiate function returns an abstract Object reference, that's why it effectively instantiates the object but it is also gives you a type error.

What you need to do, in order to access your Player script, is something similar to the following

```
GameObject obj;
obj = Instantiate(playerPrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
Player player = obj.GetComponent<Player>();
```

And that's it.